# Test Container setup failed with TestNG BeforeSuite

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testcontainers

Facing issue while running web driver module along with test container setup.

**BaseTest.java**

```
package com.testautoamtion.webdriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testcontainers.Testcontainers;
import org.testcontainers.containers.BrowserWebDriverContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

public class BaseTest {

        private static String imageName = "selenium/standalone-chrome-debug";
        private static String imageTag = "3.141.59";
        protected static BrowserWebDriverContainer<?> chrome = null;
        
        @BeforeSuite
        public static void setUp() {
            DockerImageName image = DockerImageName.parse(imageName).withTag(imageTag);
            chrome = new BrowserWebDriverContainer<>(image).withCapabilities(new ChromeOptions());
            chrome.start();
        }
        
        @AfterSuite
        public static void tearDown() {
            if(chrome.isRunning()) {
                chrome.close();
                chrome.stop();
            }
        }
    }
```

On the docker console its starts the chrome driver and automatically crashes it again.
Getting multiple exceptions like "containerLaunchException","RetryCountExceededException",
"TimeoutException","WebDriverException".

**Error log**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
[TestNGContentHandler] [WARN] It is strongly recommended to add "<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >" at the top of your file, otherwise TestNG may fail or not work as expected.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation MDCAdapter implementation.
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#no_static_mdc_binder for further details.
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite setUp
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:334)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:315)
    at com.testautoamtion.webdriver.BaseTest.setUp(BaseTest.java:22)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:401)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:88)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:327)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:523)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:329)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for result with exception
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:54)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.BrowserWebDriverContainer.containerIsStarted(BrowserWebDriverContainer.java:276)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.containerIsStarted(GenericContainer.java:685)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:502)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'c9a85a6ba580', ip: '172.17.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '1.8.0_292'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x5628452658f3 <unknown>
#1 0x562844d4aba8 <unknown>
#2 0x562844d6de33 <unknown>
#3 0x562844d699ef <unknown>
#4 0x562844da3995 <unknown>
#5 0x562844d9dd63 <unknown>
#6 0x562844d74144 <unknown>
#7 0x562844d75135 <unknown>
#8 0x562845294c3e <unknown>
#9 0x5628452aa6b7 <unknown>
#10 0x562845295b95 <unknown>
#11 0x5628452abb05 <unknown>
#12 0x56284528a2ab <unknown>
#13 0x5628452c6248 <unknown>
#14 0x5628452c63c8 <unknown>
#15 0x5628452e133d <unknown>
#16 0x7f00202d1609 start_thread

Command duration or timeout: 302 milliseconds
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor22.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:54)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1002)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.BrowserWebDriverContainer.lambda$null$0(BrowserWebDriverContainer.java:279)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.lambda$retryUntilSuccess$0(Unreliables.java:43)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'c9a85a6ba580', ip: '172.17.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '1.8.0_292'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x5628452658f3 <unknown>
#1 0x562844d4aba8 <unknown>
#2 0x562844d6de33 <unknown>
#3 0x562844d699ef <unknown>
#4 0x562844da3995 <unknown>
#5 0x562844d9dd63 <unknown>
#6 0x562844d74144 <unknown>
#7 0x562844d75135 <unknown>
#8 0x562845294c3e <unknown>
#9 0x5628452aa6b7 <unknown>
#10 0x562845295b95 <unknown>
#11 0x5628452abb05 <unknown>
#12 0x56284528a2ab <unknown>
#13 0x5628452c6248 <unknown>
#14 0x5628452c63c8 <unknown>
#15 0x5628452e133d <unknown>
#16 0x7f00202d1609 start_thread

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-R27S5VH3', ip: '192.168.1.8', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor14.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.RemoteSession$Factory.performHandshake(RemoteSession.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory.apply(ServicedSession.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$12(ActiveSessionFactory.java:180)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:440)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.apply(ActiveSessionFactory.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$null$2(NewSessionPipeline.java:66)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4719)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$createNewSession$3(NewSessionPipeline.java:69)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.DistinctOps$1$2.accept(DistinctOps.java:175)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.tryAdvance(Streams.java:405)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.tryAdvance(Streams.java:728)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.createNewSession(NewSessionPipeline.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession.execute(BeginSession.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$0(WebDriverServlet.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

SKIPPED: test
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:334)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:315)
    at com.testautoamtion.webdriver.BaseTest.setUp(BaseTest.java:22)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:401)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:88)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:327)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:523)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:329)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for result with exception
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:54)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.BrowserWebDriverContainer.containerIsStarted(BrowserWebDriverContainer.java:276)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.containerIsStarted(GenericContainer.java:685)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:502)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'c9a85a6ba580', ip: '172.17.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '1.8.0_292'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x5628452658f3 <unknown>
#1 0x562844d4aba8 <unknown>
#2 0x562844d6de33 <unknown>
#3 0x562844d699ef <unknown>
#4 0x562844da3995 <unknown>
#5 0x562844d9dd63 <unknown>
#6 0x562844d74144 <unknown>
#7 0x562844d75135 <unknown>
#8 0x562845294c3e <unknown>
#9 0x5628452aa6b7 <unknown>
#10 0x562845295b95 <unknown>
#11 0x5628452abb05 <unknown>
#12 0x56284528a2ab <unknown>
#13 0x5628452c6248 <unknown>
#14 0x5628452c63c8 <unknown>
#15 0x5628452e133d <unknown>
#16 0x7f00202d1609 start_thread

Command duration or timeout: 302 milliseconds
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor22.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:54)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1002)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.BrowserWebDriverContainer.lambda$null$0(BrowserWebDriverContainer.java:279)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.lambda$retryUntilSuccess$0(Unreliables.java:43)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'c9a85a6ba580', ip: '172.17.0.5', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '1.8.0_292'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x5628452658f3 <unknown>
#1 0x562844d4aba8 <unknown>
#2 0x562844d6de33 <unknown>
#3 0x562844d699ef <unknown>
#4 0x562844da3995 <unknown>
#5 0x562844d9dd63 <unknown>
#6 0x562844d74144 <unknown>
#7 0x562844d75135 <unknown>
#8 0x562845294c3e <unknown>
#9 0x5628452aa6b7 <unknown>
#10 0x562845295b95 <unknown>
#11 0x5628452abb05 <unknown>
#12 0x56284528a2ab <unknown>
#13 0x5628452c6248 <unknown>
#14 0x5628452c63c8 <unknown>
#15 0x5628452e133d <unknown>
#16 0x7f00202d1609 start_thread

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-R27S5VH3', ip: '192.168.1.8', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor14.newInstance(Unknown Source)



===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
===============================================
```

**Note:**

> Able to run docker images and containers manually from UI and CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chrome = new BrowserWebDriverContainer<>(image)
        .withCapabilities(new ChromeOptions().addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"));
```

Adding "--disable-dev-shm-usage" we can solve this issue.